# I can't even see how can i solve this truss question

Tags: civil-engineering, statics

I can't even see how can I solve this truss question 
I'm an engineering student, our professor assigned us this truss problem.
I have found an answer saying that it is a zero member.

I have tried but I couldn't even see where should I start from.

[image: question]

update [answer attempt]

i am working on this problem but i couldn't find any value once i reach a joint with 2 unknowns

[image: 1]

like this joint for example [B]
[[image: 2]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mbNZ.jpg)

i have even used the momentum equation but i can't go anymore
[image: 4]

Comment: I can't give a full answer right now, but I can tell you HI isn't a zero-force member. It would be if the top chord (FH and its mirror) were horizontal, but they're not.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your help

Comment: Seriously it's much easier to put the fraction values instead of the cosine or sine values. I don't understand the need to calculate the angles. On the side note, check out my answer.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

https://mathalino.com/reviewer/engineering-mechanics/problem-430-parker-truss-method-sections

i have the found the answer here

it is a similar question and it is solved in details

good luck

also take a look on the simple model made by wasabi it will help you for sure

he used ftool for it

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Because of symmetry we can cut the truss from the center and assign half of 123 kN to each half.

$$  \Sigma M_a=0 \quad 123*7.5+ 123*15+123*22.5+ 123/2*30- F_{H, \  Horizontal}*10.8=0$$

.

$$ F_{H Horizontal}= 7380/10.8 =683kN $$

.

$$ F_{HF}= 683sec(\frac{10.8-10.5}{7.5} )=683* sec(0.000698)= 683*1.0000000001=683000000051kN \ copression$$

** Edit**

A quick inspection of the very small cord angle at FH shows the force in IH is very small tension and is negligible.

$$  F_{IH}= 683*0.3/7.5=27.3kN 27.3*2 = 54.6kN \quad \text{for both sides}$$

Comment: The question is asking for the force in HI, not HF. Also, I made a [simple model on Ftool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMqzV.png) and got 683.9kN for HF.

Comment: Ok i look at it.

Comment: Just need to double it since you have the tension coming from both sides of the truss.

Comment: @kamran Can you point me to some materials about the symmetry thing (giving half of 123 kN to each side) that was done in the beginning.

Comment: @Manu G, off the top of my head no. I am sure if you Google it you find a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Solve for the reactions at the joints.
[image: Step 1]

Step 2: Take the section across FI, and then solve for the three unknowns.
[image: Step 2]

Step 3: Finally take the FBD at joint H and then solve for the values.
[image: Step 3]

The answer I got seems to put HI in **tension** at **54.67 kN**.

EDIT 1: Mistake in support reaction (@Wasabi thanks for pointing it out)

EDIT 2: Didn't put the external forces when I took the section across FI

P.S. @Wasabi thanks for pointing out the problem. Finally fixed the issue.

Comment: I'd suggest checking your work. Using a program, I go [a different result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMqzV.png) (IH = 54.7kN in tension). One thing that caught my eye is your support reaction doesn't seem right: symmetry demands that the supports have equal vertical reactions, therefore it should be simple to obtain reactions of $7\times123/2 = 430.5\text{ kN}$.

Comment: Gotcha, seems like I messed up a little there.

Comment: both of you are a little up mistaken the answer is actually compressed

Comment: Got the answer to be 95.67 kN in tension. I'll edit the answers right now.

Comment: @Wasabi can you check out what the problem is with my answer.

Comment: @YyyUuu: I can guarantee to you that it isn't in compression. If your book says it is, it's wrong.

Comment: @Wasabi Fixed the mistakes I made when solving the problem. And thanks for going through the trouble to verifying the answer. BTW, Ftool looks like a good software.

Comment: @ManuG I'm biased since I was responsible for the development of the latest version (4.0), but it really is fantastic software. I used it as an undergrad and master's student, and sometimes even as a professional engineer (for simpler structures, obviously).

Comment: @Wasabi Took a little time to get around the interface. But found it much better than the other software that I find when I just Google for Truss Solvers. It's a really good software. Kudos to making it and allowing it free access.

Comment: @Wasabi i tried another method and got another answer if you take the moment at any joint you will get a different answer where a =553.5   how could it be different

Comment: @123321 I also got the value of 553.5 kN for the reaction at support A. It's because you solved like this {Ay x 60 = 123(60 + 52.5 + 45 + 37.5 + 30 + 22.5 + 15 + 7.5)}. The issue here is that there is external force 60 m away from joint A. Compare with the answer I posted here.